# Merging multiple array then sorting by array value count

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, merge, array-merge

Please help me, i need to merge multiple arrays then sorting it by array value count. Below is the problem:

```
$array1 = array("abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno");
$array2 = array("mno", "jkl", "mno", "ghi", "pqr", "stu");
$array3 = array_merge($array1, $array2);
$array4 = ???

print_r($array4);
```

I want the returns of `$array4` like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => mno
[1] => ghi
[2] => jkl
[3] => abc
[4] => def
[5] => pqr
[6] => stu
)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do:

```
$array1 = array("abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno");
$array2 = array("mno", "jkl", "mno", "ghi", "pqr", "stu");
$array3 = array_merge($array1, $array2);

// get the array of count.
$array4 = array_count_values($array3);

// sort it in reverse order.
arsort($array4);

// extract just the keys.
$array4 = array_keys($array4);
```

[**Working example**](http://www.ideone.com/spKd6)

Comment: by the way, is it possible to merge 3 or more arrays?

Comment: @Sofyan: Yes, you can merge **any number** of arrays using `array_merge` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php