# Merging several array values into 1 array

Tags: php

I have 4 arrays for input errors like:

```
$username_errors=array();
$email_errors=array();
$password_errors=array();
$errors=array();
```

I want to merge all the arrays values in `$errors` array and count if `$errors` is empty then proceed.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well you could show us what you tried before anything. Anyway, you should look at `array_merge` function http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: you could use the `array_push()`. like `array_push($errors,$username_errors);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merging multiple array then sorting by array value count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736635/merging-multiple-array-then-sorting-by-array-value-count)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use array_merge

```
$arr = array_merge($arr1, $arr2, $arr3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array3 = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```